# requests module return json with items unordered

Tags: python, python-requests

When I'm using python's `requests` module this way:

`response = requests.get('http://[some_api_url]')
 print response.json()`

I get different json ordered in contrary to viewing the json via browser.

For example:
Via response.json() I get:
`[{"key2":"value2"},{"key1:"value1"}]`

Whereas via browser I see it as supposed to be:
`[{"key1:"value1"},{"key2":"value2"}]`

**EDIT:** When printing `response.text` its in the right order
But not json

Comment: Can you post the url please?

Comment: Unfortunately not, its not public URL

Comment: The call returns a Python data structure which includes dictionaries. Dictionaries are unordered in Python.

Comment: I usually use :

    `json.loads(response.text parse_float=float, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)`

with OrderedDict coming from `collections`

Comment: @stellasia: Thanks, I found this solution myself, but is there a way to use requests.json() in an ordered manner?

Comment: In CPython 3.6 a [new `dict` implementation was introduced that preserved insertion order](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-compactdict), however this behaviour wasn't guarenteed by the language. As of Python 3.7, it is now guarenteed that [`dict` keeps insertion order](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-December/151283.html). This should avoid the need for explicitly using a `OrderedDict`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use the `object_pairs_hook` argument of the json module as suggested in the [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load):

> object_pairs_hook is an optional function that will be called with the result of any object literal decoded with an ordered list of pairs. The return value of object_pairs_hook will be used instead of the dict. This feature can be used to implement custom decoders that rely on the order that the key and value pairs are decoded (for example, collections.OrderedDict() will remember the order of insertion). If object_hook is also defined, the object_pairs_hook takes priority.

```
import json
from collections import OrderedDict
result = json.loads(request.text,
                    object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
```

To get simpler, you can see in the [implementation of requests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/models.py#L785) that kwargs are passed from the json method to the json module, hence this works as well:

```
d = response.json(object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
```

and `d` will be an `OrderedDict` with the order of `response.text` preserved.

Comment: I verified the second approach with `d = response.json(object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)` and it works great.

Comment: Please change object_parir_hook to object_pairs_hook

Comment: Wow this is extremely helpful. Not sure how I've gone all this time without this. Thank you sir!